# Print Pointer Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I would like print the following char Array.

```
#define LENGTH 8

int main (){

    typedef char Arr[LENGTH];
    Arr test  = {1,0,1};
    Arr* a = &test;
    for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++){
        printf("%s ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your compile errors first.

Comment: I can compile this so

Comment: Fix your warnings as well

Comment: so, now the code are compile and i have no warnings.

Comment: I thing, i defined a array with the length 8, but i write only 3 elements..

Answer (score 2):

fixing your many errors and re-editing to use strlen:

```
#define LENGTH 8
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    typedef char Arr[LENGTH];
    Arr test  = {'1','0','1'};
    Arr* a = &test;
    size_t len = strlen(test);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%c ", (*a)[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so nice, i correct my errors. now its work.

Comment: it is possible to use sizeof and find the size of the pointer array?

Comment: gathering from your other question, I understand you mean to find the string len(not sizeof).
To do that, use strlen(test)

Comment: if this post answers your question, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. You are using `%s`, which is for strings. Use `%c` for characters.
2. You need `(*a)[i]`, as `a` is a pointer to an array, so `*a` is an array.
3. 1 and 0 encode non-printable characters. So you won't see anything.

Comment: And the biggest of all: **never typedef arrays or pointers**.

Comment: @Silidrone it is a problem. It is a human error :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah it's bad practice.